# Send email reminder if a task is not complete

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, workflow

I know other people already asked this questions, but I could not figure out how to do it. It would be a big help for me if it is step by step...

In my task list, I have a "Project log-in" and a "Due Date" columns. I would like to create a WF that could send a reminder email to the Assignees 7 day prior to the due date. How would I do this?

Thank you,
Dennis

Comment: Followed the instruction from other thread, here is what i did, but still doesn't work! May be something is not correct. I created a calcalated new column called "Reminder Due Date" with a formular: [Due Date]-7, then created a WF with the following: If Current Item: "Due Date" equals "Today", then pause unit Current Item: "Reminder Due Date", then email to.... Is there something wrong in this WF?

Answer (score 0):

To do this you'll need to create another field for Due Date Reminder.  I believe you can make that a calculated field that is equal to Due Date - 7 days.  You'll also need to create a workflow that kicks off the email to the desired recipients.

For your Task list, go to List Settings

- Information management policy settings
- Click on **Task** under Content Type
- Select **Enable Retention**.  Some new text will show up
- Click on **Add a retention stage...**, which will open up a modal window
- There should be a drop down for **Time Period**.  Select your DueDateReminder field.
- Under the **When this stage is triggered**, perform the following action: ** dropdown, select **Start a workflow** then select your email workflow

This should get you what you're looking for.

Comment: Our IT doesn't let us access to Imformation management policy settings. I will request an access and try your method.

Comment: If they're balking on giving you higher permissions just have them create a custom permission that just has 'Browse Directories' at the Site Collection root, and have them give you that permission.

Answer (score 0):

These reminder emails x days prior to due date sounds like such a simple thing, but often it is not. 
The first issue is to get the actual requirements right, especially the edge cases:
I have a task that is due in 9 days, then I change the due date so that it is due in 4 days..does the workflow catch this?
I now change the same due date and now the same task is due is 10 days. Should the notification be sent again in 3 days time? 
The only solution that I have made that actually covers all the cases is a daily timer job

Comment: Creating a daily timer job is the right fix and gets the job done perfectly. 
Do you have any other suggestions for SharePoint online , where do not have any deployment or server side code involved?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by deployment and server side code. You could create a powershell script and have it running as a Windows time job on a server of your choice

Comment: By server side code I mean, that does not involve C# code or any deployment inside a server, OR simply when you are dealing with SharePoint online and have only site collection permissions.

Comment: So is a powershell script in a Windows timer job ok?

Comment: I think Azure WebJob might be what should work,

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/getting-started-with-building-azure-webjobs-for-your-office365-sites

Answer (score 0):

You can use “Add Time to Date” and “Pause until Date” actions in the workflow and set the workflow steps as below:
[image]
[image]

Then, in the workflow settings, you can tick “start workflow automatically when an item is created” under Start Options.

Comment: 2nd Action: then Pause until.....There is no Variable: Date for me to choose. (Only two options; Date Value, or Lookup Date & Time from Current Item)? Can you please explain more about the second action?

Comment: In the first action, I output the due date minus 7 day to variable:date. then I can select the variable: date from workflow variable and parameter in data source section. I update the screenshot.

Comment: It works!!! Thank you very much! It works for the new item created. For the existing items, i also check "Start workflow automatically when an item is changed" Is this correct? and what it does if I check "Allow this workflow to be manually started"?

Comment: Yes, for the existing items, you can check "start...when an item changed". If we check the "allow..manually started", users can start the workflow manually though selecting an item->ITEMS/FILES tab in the ribbon->workflows->select the relevant workflow to start.

Comment: This approach might create problems, when the task is being edited during this time, until the workflow is in paused state. **Cannot update the item, it is already being edited by WORKFLOW....**

An alternative might be to run a regular site workflow and check if any of the tasks are reaching their due date?