# Trigger based email reminders

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server

there is a rule set in my Sharepoint where an email is sent to those who trigger it, what I need is to send an email reminder if X days go by and no action has been taken by the person who received the first email.

I would really appreciate any help on this, pretty inexperienced on SP.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can use “Add Time to Date” and “Pause until Date” actions in the workflow and set the workflow steps as below:

[image]

Choose: "start workflow automatically when an item is created".

Similar issue posts for your reference:

[3 days before due date email reminder workflow](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/176704/3-days-before-due-date-email-reminder-workflow/177124)

[Send email reminder if a task is not complete](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/235456/send-email-reminder-if-a-task-is-not-complete)